# How to find HCF of 2 numbers in compile time using template?

Tags: c++, templates, math

I want to calculate HCF of 2 numbers using value of enum with template recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
template<int x,int y,int r>
struct s{
    enum{e=x%r==0 && y%r==0?r:s<x,y,r-1>::e};
};

int main(){
    printf("%d\n",s<3,5,MIN(3,5)>::e);
    return 0;
};
```

which x and y are the 2 numbers,r is the value to test, the principle is that find a number to divide x and y, start from min of x and y, then decrease by 1 until a value of r can divide both x and y. But this code cannot compile because of following errors:

```
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, -252>'     requested here
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, -251>' requested here
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, -250>' requested here
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, -249>' requested here
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, -248>' requested here
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: (skipping 246 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, -1>' requested here
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, 0>' requested here
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, 1>' requested here
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, 2>' requested here
xxx.cpp:8:19: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, 3>' requested here
printf("%d\n",s<3,5,3>::e);
              ^
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: use -ftemplate-depth=N to increase recursive template instantiation depth
enum{e=x%r==0 && y%r==0?r:s<x,y,r-1>::e};
                          ^
1 error generated.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: ? won't terminate the recursion for you, the compiler will keep generating code for both sides; you'll need to add specialisations to halt evaluation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@moonshadow's comment is the core answer, but let me expand it into a full answer.

The compiler output luckily shows the relevant instantiations:

```
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, -1>' requested here
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, 0>' requested here
xxx.cpp:4:31: note: in instantiation of template class 's<3, 5, 1>' requested here
```

Let's look at the actual instantiation

```
template<int x = 3, int y = 5, int r = 0>
struct s{
    enum{e = 3%0==0 && 5%0==0 ? 0 : s<5,3,-1>::e};
};
```

Obviously, two things are wrong:

1. `3 % 0` is a division by zero
2. The instantiation of `s<5,3,-1>` is unnecessary.

This is easily fixed with `constexpr`, but let's stick with a templated solution. Recursion needs an special case for the end, and `HCF(x,y)=1` is that special case for co-primes.

```
template <int x, int y> 
struct s<x,y,1> { enum e = 1 };
```

That said, you really should use [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm) as this brute-force search won't work for something as easy as `s<300,300,300>`.